# how to bind paramquery using managed bean to remote data

Tags: jsf, data-binding, datatable, remote-server

I have an xhtml page JSF which displays html table.  Please how may I incorporate paramquery datatable instead of html table?  I have communicated with paramquery forum and received no workable reply.

xHTML CODE:

```
<h:body>
<h:dataTable width="100%" value="#{queryBean.getDataList()}" var="u"
    border="1">

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Number</f:facet>
        #{u.caseno}
    </h:column>

</h:dataTable>
```

Comment: JSF is a component based framework, you can always make your own component. However, a much easier option would be looking at already available components. Have you looked at primefaces ? They use jquery UI, and you probably will find what u r looking for

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, I have view PrimeFaces, it does not have the features of hierarchy that I am seeking.  My question is more towards data connectivity using a manged bean.

Comment: for data hierarchy you can use a [treetable] (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/treetable/basic.xhtml) component. you can see the backing end in their demo.

Comment: Hi Fareed, you are most kind.  The answer you are providing is far from my solution.  I tried PrimeFaces.  Thank you.